# updates secure from sql injections in yii

Tags: php, sql-injection, yii

Could you please tell if these 2 fragments of code secure in yii.
Fragent 1:

```
 $numberOfRows = $this->updateAll(array('full_path' => $target, 'title' => $name,                'machine_name' => $name), 'full_path = :path', array(':path' => $path));
```

Should I escape $target and $name in this query?

Fragment 2:

```
$sql = "UPDATE folders";
$sql .= " SET full_path = CONCAT('" . $target . "',SUBSTR(full_path, " . (strlen($path)  + 1) . ", LENGTH(full_path)-1))";
$sql .= " WHERE full_path LIKE '" . $path . "%'";
$command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

Should I escape $target and full_path here using
CDbConnection::quoteValue() or something like this in these 2 fragments?
I also one how to escape path in the Fragment 2 to avoid issues with special symbols used with LIKE (%, _).

I made changes to fragment 2 using binds and escaping %_:

```
$sql = "UPDATE folders";
$sql .= " SET full_path = CONCAT(:target, SUBSTR(full_path, " . (strlen($path) + 1) . ", LENGTH(full_path)-1))";
$sql .= " WHERE full_path LIKE  :pathFilter";
$command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand($sql);

//escape %_ that can be used in SQL LIKE expression
$pathFilter = addcslashes($path, '%_') . '%';

$command->bindParam(":pathFilter", $pathFilter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":target", $target, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$command->execute();
```

Is it correct? Is there a more elegent way to do it?

Comment: Use Binding parameters I guess http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters

Comment: Answering question by question doesn't make much sense, right?)))

Comment: I think the first fragment in safe, but second the fragment doesn't seem safe.

Comment: It would be great if somebody could give full answer that I could accept.

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense at all. Could you please answer the question if you know it? Your remarks are absolutely useless right now.

Comment: Ok.Ok. Refer to rene's link. It's useful.

Comment: Yes, the links rene's link is useful. But I wonder what do you with variable that is used with LIKE and how to avoid problems with it. Binding doesn't seem enough in this case, right?

Comment: You need to bind **complete string literal**

Comment: I added example, how I rewrote Fragment 2.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean: "You need to bind complete string literal"

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of more elegant ways, you can always avoid named parameters, which will dramatically shorten your code:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE folders SET";
$sql .= " full_path = CONCAT(?, SUBSTR(full_path, ?, LENGTH(full_path)-1))";
$sql .= " WHERE full_path LIKE ?";

//escape %,_ and \ that can be used in SQL LIKE expression
$pathFilter = addcslashes($path, '\%_') . '%'; // I've added a slash here

$command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute([$target, strlen($path) + 1, $pathFilter]);
```

Comment: It seems to me  positional parameters marked with "?" won't work in yii.

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but they write here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/: "Side note on positional parameters

As of now (Yii 1.1.8), the framework does not recognized positional parameters marked with "?". You have to used named parameters whose names begin with ":"."

Comment: Why do you escape \ as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

a) use a model object e.g in your case you can have model class for folder table 
     and any other associated table where you are inserting/updating data. This will help you work with set of models (if that suits you ). Model class have built-in functions to validate data before inserting into data base . e.g [CActiveRecord save method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail).Further [read this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/) for related security details

using lets say you have `Folder` model:

```
 $path='path to be updated';
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->compare('full_path',$path,true);
  $folder=Folder::model()->find($criteria);
  if($folder){
   $folder->attributes=$data;
    if($folder->save()){
      echo 'updated successfully';
    }else{
      echo 'invalid data';
    }
  }
```

b) If creating model class  is not desired, use [Binding Parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindParam-detail) 
     [Details article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) ,see #5 Binding Parameters

Assuming you construct the $full_path and $path variables

```
  //$full_path=[construct using php]
  //$path=[construct using php]
  $sql = "UPDATE folders SET full_path = :newPath  WHERE full_path LIKE :oldPath"
  $command = $this->dbConnection->createCommand($sql);
  $command->bindParam(":newPath", $full_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $old_path=addcslashes($path,'%_').'%'; 
  $command->bindParam(":oldPath", $old_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $command->execute();
```

hope this will be helpfull

Comment: I have model folders and code that I use is call from one of its methods.

Comment: 1. Why don't you escape %,_ in path using it in LIKE expression?

Comment: 2.  $command->bindParam(":oldPath", "%{$path}%", PDO::PARAM_STR); I need LIKE path%, not  %path%.

Comment: 3. $command->bindParam(":oldPath", "%{$path}%", PDO::PARAM_STR); will not work as second parameter is pass by reference, right?

Comment: Updating data using seems better than reading data and then updating it, right?

Comment: @Oleg ,it all depends on how you want to process your data , I have given you both options . Models are best when used with other set of models and controllers (say it using in MVC architecture). Second option suits you best . For your question of escaping % I am not sure what kind of query you are constructing . Write the plan sql query you want to construct  I ll try that . if you need 'path%' search try this:`$command->bindParam(":oldPath", "{$path}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: .And remember the $path argument is not passed by reference. Its php construct to e.g `"My name is {$first_name} {$last_name}"` to parse variable with in string

Comment: public function bindParam($name, &$value, $dataType=null, $length=null, $driverOptions=null)
 {
  $this->prepare();
  if($dataType===null)
   $this->_statement->bindParam($name,$value,$this->_connection->getPdoType(gettype($value)));
  elseif($length===null)
   $this->_statement->bindParam($name,$value,$dataType);
  elseif($driverOptions===null)
   $this->_statement->bindParam($name,$value,$dataType,$length);
  else
   $this->_statement->bindParam($name,$value,$dataType,$length,$driverOptions);
  $this->_paramLog[$name]=&$value;
  return $this;
 }

Comment: What issue I mean about % in your example: if path contains % or _ (it's possible), your example will not work correctly, because this symbol has special meaning for SQL LIKE operator. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Oleg read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php to get idea of curly braces with string. Its not passing by reference thing its STRING PARSING with variables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38760/discussion-between-sakhunzai-and-oleg)

Comment: I don't say that {$variable} is passing by reference itself, what I mean if you try to execute your code it will fail, because bindParam passes second param as reference.

Comment: @sorry for confusion , the answer is updated as per our discussion. thanks for pointing out the issue in the code